# Was it necessary to have $g(x)\neq4$ and $x\neq4$ in the assumptions of this problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Suppose $f'(4)=3 , g'(4)=7,g(4)=4,g(x)=4,g(x)\neq4$ for $x\neq4$ find:
>
> $1)$$\lim_{x\to4}\frac{f(x)-f(4)}{g(x)-4}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad2)\lim_{x\to4}\frac{f(g(x))-f(4)}{x-4}$

I know how to solve this problem ( we can do it by rewriting first one as $\lim_{x\to4}\dfrac{{\frac{f(x)-f(4)}{x-4}} }{\frac{g(x)-g(4)}{x-4}}$ and second one as $\lim_{x\to4}\dfrac{f(g(x))-f(g(4))}{g(x)-g(4)}\times\dfrac{g(x)-g(4)}{x-4}$ and using defenition of derivative.)

My question : Was it necessary to say $g(x)\neq4$ and finding the values for $x\neq4$? I also don't understand how $g(x)\neq4$ if we have $g(x)=4$ in the assumptions.

Comment: Either there is a typo or you have copied the question  wrongly. The first line makes no sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I rechecked it from my book and realized I copied it correctly. maybe there is typo in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first limit to exist, it's necessary that there exists a small interval $(4-\delta,4+\delta)$ in which $g(x)\ne4$ except for $g(4)=4$ itself. (If there is no such interval, then the quotient is undefined at a sequence of points tending to $x=4$, which means the limit cannot be defined.)

Rather than bother saying the bit about the interval $(4-\delta,4+\delta)$, I believe the writer chose a simpler hypothesis, namely that $g(x)\ne4$ for $x\ne4$. This is stronger than is really required (as discussed above), but simpler to say and to deal with. But the real point is to just ensure that the quotient itself is defined enough to make the limit make sense in the first place.